# Multiple JOINs to the same subquery expression

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I've recently been teaching myself SQL, and have been working on a toy project to do so. Here is a sample schema:

```
CREATE TABLE user (
  id INT PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  name VARCHAR(50)
);

INSERT INTO user(name) VALUES
  ("User 1"),
  ("User 2"),
  ("User 3"),
  ("User 4"),
  ("User 5");

CREATE TABLE friendship (
  uid_1 INT,
  uid_2 INT,
  accepted_time TIMESTAMP NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  PRIMARY KEY (uid_1, uid_2),
  CONSTRAINT fk_uid_1 FOREIGN KEY (uid_1) REFERENCES user (id),
  CONSTRAINT fk_uid_2 FOREIGN KEY (uid_2) REFERENCES user (id)
);

INSERT INTO friendship(uid_1, uid_2) VALUES
  (1, 2),
  (2, 1);

CREATE TABLE event (
  id INT PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  name VARCHAR(50),
  owner_id INT,
  CONSTRAINT fk_owner_id FOREIGN KEY (owner_id) REFERENCES user (id)
);

INSERT INTO event (name, owner_id) VALUES
 ("Event 1", 1),
 ("Event 2", 2),
 ("Event 3", 3),
 ("Event 4", 4),
 ("Event 5", 5),
 ("Event 6", 1);

CREATE TABLE invite (
  event_id INT NOT NULL,
  sent_from_id INT NOT NULL,
  sent_to_id INT NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (event_id, sent_to_id),
  CONSTRAINT fk_event_id FOREIGN KEY (event_id) REFERENCES event (id),
  CONSTRAINT fk_sent_from_id FOREIGN KEY (sent_from_id) REFERENCES user (id),
  CONSTRAINT fk_sent_to_id FOREIGN KEY (sent_to_id) REFERENCES user (id)
);

INSERT INTO invite(event_id, sent_from_id, sent_to_id) VALUES
  (1, 2, 3);
```

As part of this project, I have a query that gets a list of users, with information populated relative to the currently authenticated user.

A simplified version of the query looks like this:

```
$select_users_query = "

SELECT
    user.id AS id,
    user.name AS name,
    friendship.accepted_time AS friend_since
FROM user
LEFT JOIN friendship
    ON friendship.uid_1 = user.id AND friendship.uid_2 = $relative_to_id

";
```

Then, at some endpoints, I want to return objects which have one or more users as sub-objects. In order to do this, I've been `JOIN`ing tables to the above query as a subquery, but when the returned object has multiple users (e.g., an invite to an event has a sending user, a receiving user, and a user that owns the event in question), the resulting query can end up pretty repetitive:

```
$select_invites_query = "

SELECT
    event.id AS event_id,
    event.name AS event_name,

    owner.id AS owner_id,
    owner.name AS owner_name,
    owner.friend_since AS owner_friend_since,

    sent_to.id AS sent_to_id,
    sent_to.name AS sent_to_name,
    sent_to.friend_since AS sent_to_friend_since,

    sent_from.id AS sent_from_id,
    sent_from.name AS sent_from_name,
    sent_from.friend_since AS sent_from_friend_since,

FROM invite

INNER JOIN event
    ON event.id = invite.event_id

INNER JOIN ($select_users_query) owner
    ON event.owner_id = owner.id

INNER JOIN ($select_users_query) sent_from
    ON invite.sent_from_id = sent_from.id

INNER JOIN ($select_users_query) sent_to
    ON invite.sent_to_id = sent_to.id

";
```

My questions are:

1. Is repeating a subquery like this a performance issue during execution, assuming that the `INNER JOIN`s all match on just a single row?
2. If not, is the additional parsing required for `$select_invites_query` a significant concern at all (especially as `$select_users_query` grows big and complex)?
3. Would using a variable here be a good idea, or a bad idea? From my inspection of `EXPLAIN` it seems as though MySQL is able to handle these `JOIN`s pretty efficiently, but would defining a variable force MySQL to pull the unfiltered result set into memory before `JOIN`ing?

See SQL Fiddle schema [here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/f02cd/1/0).

Comment: Thanks, will provide shortly.

Comment: Instead of repetitively using query as a sub-query better create a join for user and friendship table as well. 3 time repeating same query means doing same thing three times by joining these 2 table definitely there will be a performance improvement.

Comment: @NandanRana Could you clarify what exactly you mean? How would you change the joining strategy?

Comment: @Strawberry Added a link to the SQL Fiddle setup.

Comment: What is your version of MySQL? With 8+, you can take advantage of CTEs.

Comment: @Parfait That looks like just the kind of thing I was looking for. I was on an older version, but I've updated now to use CTEs. If you want to flesh out an answer on CTEs I'd be happy to accept.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you appear to need self joins of same query, consider a [Common Table Expression (CTE)](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/with.html) (available in MySQL 8.0+) and with PHP parameterization. Below demonstrates with PHP's [`mysqli`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.prepare.php) API in object-oriented and procedural styles:

```
$select_invites_query = "
 WITH sub AS (
    SELECT u.id AS id, u.`name` AS `name`, 
           f.accepted_time AS friend_since 
    FROM user 
    LEFT JOIN friendship f
          ON f.uid_1 = u.id AND f.uid_2 = ?
 )

 SELECT event.id AS event_id, event.`name` AS event_name, 
        owner.id AS owner_id, owner.`name` AS owner_name, 
        owner.friend_since AS owner_friend_since,

        sent_to.id AS sent_to_id, sent_to.`name` AS sent_to_name, 
        sent_to.friend_since AS sent_to_friend_since, 

        sent_from.id AS sent_from_id, sent_from.`name` AS sent_from_name, 
        sent_from.friend_since AS sent_from_friend_since

 FROM invite 
 INNER JOIN event 
    ON event.id = invite.event_id 
 INNER JOIN sub owner 
    ON event.owner_id = owner.id 
 INNER JOIN sub sent_from 
    ON invite.sent_from_id = sent_from.id 
 INNER JOIN sub sent_to 
    ON invite.sent_to_id = sent_to.id";

// OBJECT-ORIENTED STYLE
$conn = new mysqli("my_host", "my_user", "my_pwd", "my_db");
$stmt = $conn->prepare($select_invites_query))
$stmt->bind_param("i", $relative_to_id);
$stmt->execute();
...

// PROCEDURAL STYLE     
$conn = mysqli_connect("my_host", "my_user", "my_pwd", "my_db");
$stmt = mysqli_prepare($conn, $select_invites_query);
mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, "i", $relative_to_id); 
mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt); 
...
```